# HawtIO + Camel plugin - Multiple context not showing up - Limits to max3

Tags: spring, apache-camel, hawtio

Our application is enterprise application which contains multiple web application. Each web application contains one or more camel context. Recently we are exploring the option of using HawtIO for monitoring and administrative purposes. 
We are using camel (fuse) version -**2.12.0.redhat-610379** with **Wildfly 8.1**(Dev env -prod being WAS8.5). I have tried with HawtIO web app version ranging from 1.4.10 to 14 and with no-slf4j version as well. But HawtIO is showing maximum 3 camelcontext only. I have tried giving managementNamePattern as well but still no postive results. 
If I comment out some of listed camel contexts then other one are getting listed. Please note that each camel context would contain around 10 to 15 routes and endpoint (spring beans) will be around 30 . 
But I am able to find unlisted camel context in JMX Dashboard under org.apache.camel. Kindly let me know any work around for it or if I am missing something in configuration. My camel context would refer multiple route context.

Comment: Have you found a reason for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I could not find root cause. I havent managed do selective loading of routes/camel context with help of spring.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if you still need to know this, but what you may need to do is in the HawtIO preferences, under Jolokia, increase the "Max Collection Size", as HawtIO just grabs everything and then appears to filter on the client side, so if you have a lot of MBeans, you won't see everything (as it only fetches the first 500 entries by default).

I had a similar issue - but while I was seeing all the camel contexts, I was not seeing all the routes, which was the big issue for me.

It defaults to 500. I increased it to 5000, which was enough for me. You may wish to try fiddling with that yourself, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I increased this value and the depth value for jolokia and it showed more camel contexts, excellent suggestion.

Comment: Do you think this also may work for ActiveMQ plug in? Same problem, it shows max 500 rows by default...

Comment: Maybe. I haven't used it before, and I'm no longer using HawtIO & Camel, so the best I can suggest would be to experiment and see what happens.