# Hawtio ActiveMQ queue Browse shows maximum 500 messages

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio

I'm trying to see all the messages in my queue in ActiveMQ(5.11.1). I am using Hawtio(1.4.51) for this purpose. My queue in ActiveMQ contains 790 message.

My Steps till now:

1. By default hawtio shows up to 400 Messages in ActiveMQ queue. So i went to my broker.xml settings and added:

```html
<destinationPolicy>
 <policyMap>
  <policyEntries>
   <policyEntry queue="incoming.status" maxBrowsePageSize="401"/> 
  </policyEntries>
 </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

This gave me 401 messages.

2. So i tried to change the maxBrowsePageSize="401" to "-1". To my surprise i got only 200 messages...
3. Next try was to set maxBrowsePageSize="1000" and again dissapointement. I could see only 500 messages...
4. Next i went to my java code and inserted:

```js
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("c:\\Messages.log", "UTF-8");
writer.write(jmsQueueEndpoint.browseAllMessagesAsXml(true));
writer.close();
```

The results were: for maxBrowsePageSize="401" i got 401/790 messages, for "2" i got 2/790 for "1000" and for "-1" i got 790/790.

So my conclusion was that there is some setting in Hawtio that limits my results to 500.

I need to see ALL my messages in Hawtio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after more investigation, and with a help of this blog: [HawtIO + Camel plugin - Multiple context not showing up - Limits to max3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282038/hawtio-camel-plugin-multiple-context-not-showing-up-limits-to-max3)

I was able to find the setting which will allow ActiveMQ in Hawtion to show more than 500 entries. The setting located here:

- In the right side of hawtio application there is your user picture with a small arrow. Press on it and select "Preferences".

[image]

- In "Preferences" select "Jolokia.

[image]

- In "Jolokia" edit: "Max collection size" to maximum that you want and press "apply", restart browser.

[image]

The only problem left is the unlimited option. When i set "-1" in the broker part, hawtio limits me to 200 entries...